# How to loop an arithmetic matrix operation in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix with 253 columns and 1000 rows, I am trying to create perhaps a for loop or another repeatable function whereby I can subtract the 253rd value of each row from the first, i.e. if the matrix is defined M, the operation I'm attempting is: M[1]-M[253], for all 1000 rows, and then storing these 1000 values in a single row vector. Is it possible to create a loop for this?

I've tried using this:

```
uloss <- M[,1] - M[,253]
```

But I'm still unsure if this is correct, thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You definitely do not need for loop here. R heavily relies on *vectorized* methods, so your approach is the most *natural* for R.

Comment: `m[, 253] - m[,1]` is actually what you are looking for.

Comment: Karthik, I think the OP has the right ordering.  His equation should work.

Comment: @SteveM Thanks for the response, as it turns out, you are right and I was already correct but I was reading the results incorrectly, thanks for the help!